# Google Map static map not working in Visualforce pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf, google-map

I have a page which is being rendered as pdf and in it there is a google static maps image which is not being displayed.
This used to work fine but for some reason seems to have stopped working.

The image displays fine if the page is not rendered as a pdf.

https://maps.googleapis.com is included in the Remote Site settings.

The Google Maps API key has had restrictions turned off on it as I thought maybe the pdf render engine was hitting it from a different url to the normal ones.

Any advice or even confirmation from others if they can render google static maps in a visualforce pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would suggest moving away from your own Google Maps API keys, and the hassel of managing remote sites, and implement the  tag in Visualforce - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_map.htm

If you replace your code with this, does it render as PDF?

Comment: It will not work since it is JavaScript-based map, which does not work in PDF renderer engine